# Dependency Injection: Spring and Java

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I recently started to use the Spring Framework. 
In a book I found this example:

```
public class DamselRescuingKnight implements Knight {

   private RescueDamselQuest quest;

   public DamselRescuingKnight() {
      this.quest = new RescueDamselQuest();
   }

   public void embarkOnQuest() {
      quest.embark();
   }
}
```

Using Spring Constructor Dependency Injection, the example becomes:

```
public class DamselRescuingKnight implements Knight {

   private Quest quest;

   public DamselRescuingKnight(Quest quest) {
      this.quest = quest;
   }

   public void embarkOnQuest() {
      quest.embark();
   }
}
```

While the xml file configuration is:

```
<bean id="knight" class="com.springinaction.knights.DamselRescuingKnight">
   <constructor-arg ref="quest" />
</bean>

<bean id="quest" class="com.springinaction.knights.somethingThatImplementsQuest">
</bean>
```

In order to completely understand the concept,
could you write an alternative example of Dependency Injection of the same classes using *only Java* (without Spring, so without the xml file)?

Comment: Java does not natively implement DI outside the concept of a container of some kind.  The "container" is a set of classes that gets control before your code. It instantiates beans and injects them at the appropriate places.  The container can be Spring or a JavaEE system.  Plain JavaSE code (i.e. code that runs starting with a `main(String[])` method) does not do DI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is equivalent to the dependency injection from your configuration file. The only difference is that your `Quest` object is created after the `BraveKnight` instance.

```
public class BraveKnight {
    private Quest quest;
    public BraveKnight(Quest quest) {
        this.quest = quest;
    }
}

public class Quest {

}

public class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Quest quest = new Quest();
        BraveKnight knight = new BraveKnight(quest);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what DI does under the covers, but the whole point of DI is that your code doesn't have to worry about creating objects and wiring them together.  So it's kind of stretching things to call this DI.

Comment: So both solutions are the same...the knight isn't coupled to any specific implementation of Quest (unlike first example)....so why should I use the spring solution?